# Create a workflow/dialogue where prompt updates existing field?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am relatively new to Dynamics CRM and I have an issue on the Opportunity entity where users don't update the 'Est. Close Date'.

Therefore a lot of the dates are in the past - is there a way that a dialogue/box can appear where the user enters a new date which updates the 'Est. Close Date' field?

Comment: `Est. Close Date` for each record will be different or you wish to update one `Est. Close Date` for every record?

Comment: One Est. Close Date for each Opportunity. i.e. if a user goes on an Opportunity with an Est. Close Date in the past, there will be a flag/box and they will be able to change that individual Est. Close Date

Comment: sorry may be I was not clear in my comment, so when user opens opp and if `Est. Close Date` is not available for that record you want to force user to enter.
Not that you want to bulk update 100's of opportunity record at once?

Comment: Correct. When Est. Close Date is either not available or in the past. and yes, only for one Opportunity at a time.

Comment: did you managed to solve it? if my answer helped could you please mark it as solved, it will help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned from your comment,

Req is when user opens Opportunity Record and if Est close date is empty or < Today's date then force user to update Est close Date.

Solution:

You can achieve this using Javascript.

1. Run your Javascript on event (Onload) of opportunity
2. Check if your Form is of type update `formContext.ui.getFormType();`

You can check that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui/getformtype)

1. Now check if `Est. Close Date` is empty or less than today's date
2. if condition is satisfied that means user should enter new value for field `Est. Close Date`
3. So how can we force user to enter new value?
4. First make that field empty and then make that field Business Req.
5. In this way user will have to update value

There are few more conditions you can check such as
Onchange of `Est. Close Date`
check if `Est. Close Date` always >= todays date so that user will not enter false date.

You will have to test your all use cases.